# Composer: Where are Conflicts Between Repositories Settled in Composer's Source

Tags: php, composer-php

In [PHP Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), composer defaults to checking [packagist.org](http://packagist.org) for package locations.  It's the default composer repository.

However, per the manual, it's [possible to configure multiple repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#types).

How does composer (i.e. when in its source code) resolve conflicts between these repositories.

i.e., if you had both a VCS repository type and a custom composer repository configured in your project, and each of these had a package named [`laravel/laravel`](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/laravel), what are the rules composer would follow in deciding if the package should be

1. Downloaded from Packagist
2. Downloaded from the VCS repository
3. Downloaded from the custom composer repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the same page:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository

it said explicitly what custom repos are checked first compared to default packagist.org repo.

also - there is provided a detailed guide on what you need to do to make composer load your version over the original one.

also based on mentioning the `dev-` prefix, which should be put to the version constraint - composer most likely to compare repos and choosing one over another basing on availability of requested version in that particular repo.

I am for sure might say what composer do check custom repos first.

Basing on source code inspection those lines say that custom repositories are checked in order how they are defined, default repository being the last one:

this shows how custom repos are merged in default configuration:

```
file: composer/src/Composer/Config.php

if (!empty($config['repositories']) && is_array($config['repositories'])) {
    $this->repositories = array_reverse($this->repositories, true);
    $newRepos = array_reverse($config['repositories'], true);
    foreach ($newRepos as $name => $repository) {
        // disable a repository by name
        if (false === $repository) {
            unset($this->repositories[$name]);
            continue;
        }
        // disable a repository with an anonymous {"name": false} repo
        if (is_array($repository) && 1 === count($repository) && false === current($repository)) {
            unset($this->repositories[key($repository)]);
            continue;
        }
        // store repo
        if (is_int($name)) {
            $this->repositories[] = $repository;
        } else {
            $this->repositories[$name] = $repository;
        }
    }
    $this->repositories = array_reverse($this->repositories, true);
}
```

and this shows that repositories queried in order they stored in memory until package is found:

```
file: composer/src/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php

public function findPackage($name, $constraint)
{
    foreach ($this->repositories as $repository) {
        if ($package = $repository->findPackage($name, $constraint)) {
            return $package;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In conclusion:

1. enter point for resolving actual version to install when called a `require` command is located at:
   `composer/src/Composer/Command/InitCommand.php`
   in `determineRequirements()` method, which processes the input
2. package looked up in repos in order they are defined in composer.json
3. resolution between same versions is "first-wins"
4. if multiple repositories configured and specific constraint is given, the first repository encountered which holds the desired constraint wins.